# QTreewidget scrolling gets slowdown in case of multiple files

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I am using QTreewidget in my application. I am filling this QTreewidget on runtime with some files addresses. Now my problem is when there are excess number of files(more than 200) the scrolling gets slow down in the QTreewidget which creates problem for my further processing but when the files are less it works fine. Is there anyone who can tell me whats is the reason behind this Qtreewidget problem ?
Thanks.

Comment: If you need better performance, use QTreeView with a model: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html

Comment: thanks for your response, But i don't want to use the models. Is there any other way to solve this.

Comment: Actually that's pretty strange if `QTreeWidget` isn't changing 200 items should perform well.

Comment: "You don't want to use models" == "You don't need performance". QTreeWidget is use for small number of data.

Comment: How do you add files to model? Maybe it's a problem of file enumerator? Qt classes like QDir is too slow for large lists of files.